# Android - Get progress of paging action on a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Suppose I have a `ViewPager` which contains some views and user can page among them. I need a callback method something like `onPaging(int progress)` My purpose is I want to know how much percent of paging process is completed.
What I want from this callback method is synchronizing a page indicator(something like a couple of circles and a highlighted one for current page) with paging process.
Can anyone please offer me an idea? every ideas is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a direct answer to your question: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) can probably accomplish what you are looking for.

Why reinvent the wheel, though? Jake Wharton has created the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com) library that will address your issue very effectively. Give it a try.

Comment: Oooops! I was really forgot `onPageScrolled` of `OnPageChangeListener` Thanks for your recall :)